# integrating an equation that includes trigonometric terms and multiple constants

Tags: calculus, integration, classical-mechanics

We have the initial conditions, $v(0) = u$ and $x(0) = 0$ [we're not actually told this]. The acceleration due to gravity $g$ and the coefficient of friction $\mu'$ are constants that we do not need to find. And, $a$ is the acceleration.

we have

\begin{equation} a = -g(\sin\alpha +\mu'\cos\alpha)\\\
\end{equation}

and we need to find the distance $x$, which is

\begin{equation}x = \dfrac{u^2}{2g(\sin\alpha + \mu'\cos\alpha)}\\\ \end{equation}

I really do not know how to arrive at the equation for $x$. I assumed we could integrate twice (finding the arbitrary constants inbetween each step), but it just doesn't work - unless, I'm making a mistake.

We're not told what we're differentiating in respect to and I assumed we were differentiating in respect to $t$, but $t$ doesn't appear in the equation of $x$.

This is what  my attempt went like:

\begin{equation} 
a(t) = \dfrac{dv}{dt} = -g(\sin\alpha +\mu'\cos\alpha)\\\
\end{equation}

so,

\begin{equation}\int a \,dt = v =g(\cos\alpha-\mu'\sin\alpha) + A\\\ \end{equation}

since $v(0) = u$

\begin{equation}
 v = 2g(\cos\alpha-\mu'\sin\alpha) +u\\\
\end{equation}

After this I tried the same thing but I didn't get even close to same answer.

For context, it relates to a particle moving on an inclined plane, and the equation of $x$ desribes the distance ($x$) travelled before it comes to rest.

I've been trying to solve this for the past couple of days without any luck and we can't even ask for help otherwise they fail us and if they saw this i'd get permanently kicked out. Any help is appreciated :(

**Edit 1:** we're not actually told if the acceleration is constant or not but can I assume it is?

**Edit 2:** $\alpha$ is the angle of inclination of the surface

**Edit 3:** the block is already moving at $t=0$ by initial speed $u$

**Edit 4:** I know I did the integration wrong (I was very tired), it should be $v = -g(sin\alpha +\mu'\cos\alpha)t + A = -g(sin\alpha +\mu'\cos\alpha)t + u$

Comment: If $x(0)=0$ then $u=0$ your equations are contradicting. Also is $\alpha$ independent of $t$?

Comment: I just guessed that intial condition because we're not even told and we're given no info with regard to position or time (not even the starting position). $\alpha$ is independent of $t$, yeah. sorry for the slow reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One has to guess, but the task is probably to compute the distance until the object comes to rest. As $v(t)=u+at$ and then $x(t)=ut+\frac12at^2$, you then only need to insert $v(t)=0\implies t=-u/a$ into the second equation to get $x=-u^2/(2a)$.

Comment: thank you for your answer! that's exactly what the task is :P may I ask how you got $t=-\dfrac{u}{a}$?

Comment: Because you want to take the time that the object stops moving (resp. reverses direction).

Comment: Is it because we set $v(t) = 0$, due to us wanting to calculate the distance until the object comes to rest and \textit{at rest} the object will have velocity $v=0$? If that's the case then my initial conditions are what have been causing me problems

Comment: ahhh thank you! (we posted the comment at the same time). I'm extremely grateful for your help